# SQL error - join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am working with a Query, but it returns error:

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  cd.*,
  MIN(tmp.date_added) AS date_start,
  MAX(tmp.date_added) AS date_end,
  COUNT(tmp.order_id) AS `orders`,
  SUM(tmp.products)   AS products,
  SUM(tmp.tax)        AS tax,
  SUM(tmp.total)      AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
     o.order_id,
     (
       SELECT SUM(op.quantity)
       FROM `order_product` op
       WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
       GROUP BY op.order_id
     ) AS products,
     (
       SELECT SUM(ot.value)
       FROM `order_total` ot
       WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'tax'
       GROUP BY ot.order_id
     ) AS tax,
     o.total,
     o.date_added
   FROM `order` o
   WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'
         AND DATE(o.date_added) >= '2016-01-01'
         AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '2016-04-01'
   GROUP BY o.order_id
  ) tmp
GROUP BY WEEK(tmp.date_added),
  (
    SELECT ROUND(sum(op.total)) AS total
    FROM order_product op
      JOIN order o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
      JOIN product_to_category p2c ON op.product_id = p2c.product_id
    WHERE o.date_added > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND o.date_added < '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
      AND o.order_status_id = 3
      AND p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
  ) AS total
FROM category_description cd
JOIN category c ON c.category_id = cd.category_id
WHERE c.status=1
AND cd.language_id=1
ORDER BY cd.category_id ASC;
```

But, it gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as total from category_description cd join category c on c.categ' at line 16

Can someone tell how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `ROUND(sum(op.total)) as total`?  The subquery serves no purpose.

Comment: Would be helpful if you formatted your query so it's easier to read.

Comment: At first glance it looks like this is more than a syntax issue, your query doesn't make sense. It seems your outer select has two FROM clauses.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below query:

```
SELECT cd.*, 
MIN(tmp.date_added) AS date_start,
MAX(tmp.date_added) AS date_end,
COUNT(tmp.order_id) AS `orders`,
SUM(tmp.products) AS products, 
SUM(tmp.tax) AS tax, 
SUM(tmp.total) AS total, 
(SELECT o.order_id, (SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM `order_product` op 
WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY op.order_id) AS products, 
(SELECT SUM(ot.value) FROM `order_total` ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'tax' 
GROUP BY ot.order_id) AS tax,
(SELECT o.total, o.date_added FROM `order` o 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' AND DATE(o.date_added) >= '2016-01-01' 
AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '2016-04-01' GROUP BY o.order_id,WEEK(tmp.date_added)) AS tmp, 
(select ROUND(sum(op.total)) as total from order_product op
join order o on o.order_id = op.order_id
join product_to_category p2c on op.product_id = p2c.product_id
where o.date_added > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
and o.date_added < '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
and o.order_status_id = 3
and p2c.category_id = cd.category_id) as total 
from category_description cd join category c on c.category_id = cd.category_id 
where c.status=1 and cd.language_id=1 order by cd.category_id asc
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY WEEK(tmp.date_added), 
(select ROUND(sum(op.total)) as total from order' at line 14